# Passing whole JsonObject instead of RequestBody in HTTP Request

Tags: android, json, post, okhttp

I am creating Requestbody, adding necessary paramters to it and requesting `POST` method of `OKHTTP`.

But, Is there any way to pass the whole `JsonObject` instead of putting seperate parameters to `Object` of RequestBody ?

Thanks.

Comment: post your code ..

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to build your `jsonObject` and pass that `jsonObject` as `rawString` in `POST` method.

**Note : "Google how to pass rawString in POST methode android"**

Comment: I have build the JsonObject successfully, but no idea about passing it to POST method. Couldn't find it.

Comment: Which library are you using for `http requests`?

Answer (score 0):

To send JSON Object request we need to create RequestBody Object and Pass it into Request Object. In the RequestBody object, we have to pass Media type and post data as a string.

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json");
JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();
try {
 postdata.put("UserName", "Vishal");
 postdata.put("Email", "vishal@@##@gmail.com");
} catch(JSONException e){
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postdata.toString());

final Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("YOUR URL")
.post(body)
.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
.addHeader("Authorization", "Your Token")
.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
.build();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("message", "Your message")
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.foo.bar/index.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    // Do something with the response.
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```